# Copy only schema to existing mysql db

Tags: mysql

I have 2 db mysql at two locations, i need to copy the schema from first to the second one without hurting the data that is already existing in the II location.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Please experts help.

Comment: If columns are missing in II, or in I, what's the desired solution?

Comment: New columns have been added in first DB otherwise both first and second have same columns, in other words, there are more columns, more tables added in first db which has to be done to the second without removing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are usually too complex to allow a simple "copy".

Use Toad's database comparison/scripting tools (or something like this: http://adamspiers.org/computing/mysqldiff/) to find the differences, check and run them manually.

Comment: Thanks, manually is fine, I thought something programmatically using queries can be done to achieve this.